# Kendo UI Chart - Visualize count of returned JSON fields

Tags: json, rest, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I want to display the counts of specific retrieved fields in my pie/donut chart.
I'm retrieving data via REST and the result is in json format. The source is a list repeating values:

Example: In the following list, I'd like to get a present the number (count) of completed responses; perhaps in a second chart present the breakdown of responses by location.

```
var userResponse  = [
      {     User:  "Bob Smith", Status: "Completed", Location: "USA" },
      {     User:  "Jim Smith", Status: "In-Progress", Location: "USA" }, 
     {     User:  "Jane Smith", Status: "Completed", Location: "USA" },
     {     User:  "Bill Smith", Status: "Completed", Location: "Japan" },
     {     User:  "Kate Smith", Status: "In-Progress", Location: "Japan" },
     {     User:  "Sam Smith", Status: "In-Progress", Location: "USA" },
 ]
```

My Initialization currently looks like this:

```
$('#targetChart').kendoChart({

    dataSource: {

        data: data.d.results,

        group: {

            field: "Location",
        },

    },

    seriesDefaults: {

        type: "donut",

    },

    series: [{

        field: 'Id',

        categoryField: 'Location',
    }],

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily transform the data.  Read it into a DataSource object grouping by location and filtering for completed only. Then fetch the data and create an array of the counts for each location:

```
var pieData = [];

var respDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: userResponse,
  group: {
    field: "Location",
  },
  filter: { 
    field: "Status", 
    operator: "eq", 
    value: "Completed" },
});
  
respDS.fetch(function(){
  var view = respDS.view();
  for (var i=0; i<view.length; i++){
    var item = {};
    item.Location = view[i].value;
    item.Count = view[i].items.length;
    pieData.push(item);
  }      
});
```

You end up with:

```
[
  {Location: "Japan", Count: 1},
  {Location: "USA", Count: 2},
]
```

This can then be bound to a pie/donut.

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UwUBu)**